# Call an Operator+ function inside the += operator function in C++

Tags: c++

I have got this overloading + operator function below and I have to write another overloading += operator function. I was wondering if I can just call the + operator function inside the =+ operator function since essentially both the function are doing the same thing. If so, then what does the syntax for it look like?

Below is my + operator function. I'm trying to add 2 Dynamically allocated matrices.

```
  Matrix Matrix::operator + (const Matrix & orig) const
  {
      int length = columns * rows; 
      try
      {
          if (rows != orig.rows || columns != orig.columns)
          {
              throw 1;
          }
     }
      catch (int c)
      {
          if (c == 1)
          {
              cout << "Error. Check Matrix dimensions, they do not match." << endl; 
          }
      }
      Matrix x(rows, columns);
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
      {
          x.data[i] = data[i] + orig.data[i];
      }
      return x;
  }

 void Matrix::operator += (const Matrix & orig)
 {
    //just call the + operator function! 
 }
```

Comment: 1) Yes, you can. 2) How would you normally call the operator + function?

Comment: That is a rather useless try/catch block since all you are doing is writing to stdout before going on.  There is a semantic difference between operator + and operator += since the former is returning a new object and += is modifying this.

Comment: Normally you do it the other way around: write `operator+=` and define `operator+` in terms of it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you didn't just do `if (rows != orig.rows || columns != orig.columns) {cout << "Error. Check Matrix dimensions, they do not match." << endl; }` which would have exactly the same effect.

Comment: I have try catch because it is a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, you could make your function return a Matrix:

```
*this = *this + orig;
return *this;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call the + operator as you would do it everywhere else. One operand here is of course the parameter `orig` while the other is the object you call the operator on itself, which is `*this`.

So you could just write:

```
*this = *this + orig
```

Whether it is wise to define `operator+=` using `operator+` or if its better to do it the other way round is up to you and might depend on your implementation.

However it is usually a good idea to define the += operator as

```
Matrix& Matrix::operator+= (const Matrix & orig)
```

since you can then do things like

```
mat += otherMat += otherMat2;
```

for this, just return `*this` as Stefan Giapantzakis already pointed out.

Comment: Hey, Thanks this worked after I changed:                                                void Matrix::operator += (const Matrix & orig) to                                   Matrix& Matrix :: operator +=(const Matrix & orig)

Answer (score 1):

It is easy: just do `*this = *this + other`.

However, often it is a better idea to write `operator+=` fully, *then* write `operator+` in terms of `+=` like this:

```
Matrix& Matrix::operator+=(const Matrix &rhs) {
  try {
    if (rows != orig.rows || columns != orig.columns)
      throw "Error. Check Matrix dimensions, they do not match.";
  } catch (char const* msg) {
    std::cout << msg << std::endl; 
  }
  int length = columns * rows; 
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    data[i] += orig.data[i];
  }
  return *this;
}
friend Matrix operator+(Matrix lhs, Matrix const& rhs){
  lhs += rhs;
  return std::move(lhs);
}
```

which, as a bonus, reduxes `a+b+c+d` into creating exacly one matrix that is not move constructed.